# Join table index performance improvements concerns

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, join, indexing

To start with, I have three tables, all with a primary key and some other data. These tables are joined in a join table with ~70 million rows:
Table_1, Table_2, Table_3.

There is a primary key in this join table across `Table_3_Id, Table_1_Id, Table_2_Id` (in this order). There is also a non-clustered index over `Table_1_Id, Table_2_Id, Table_3_Id` (in this order) with a fill index of 95.

The data is filtered by Table_1_Id (I have a preset of ~100 of these Ids) and (through a join) with a property from Table_3 (so it uses Table_3_Id). Then, Table_1_Id and Table_2_Id values are returned.  This is all done in one query in the Entity Framework.

This is the query:

```
  var items = dataContext.TablesJoin.AsNoTracking()
             .Join(dataContext.Table_3.AsNoTracking(), x => x.Table_3_Id, x => x.Id, (combi, scan) => new { combi, scan })
             .Where(x => possibleIds.Contains(x.combi.Table_1_Id) && otherIds.Contains(x.scan.Other_Id))
             .Select(x => new { FirstId = x.combi.Table_1_Id, SecondId = x.combi.DeviceInformationDevices_Id })
              ToList();
```

Because this is configuration is running on SQL Server Express, I'm running into some space problems (10GB is the max). The data is roughly 2GB, but the primary key and index are a total of 5GB. Because there is also more data in the database, I'm interested in reducing the size of the index while retaining performance.

After looking at everything, I had some concerns about what is exactly used. Because of of the join I'm not entirely sure how useful it is to include Table_3_Id in the non-clustered index. Removing this column from the index saves around 1GB of space.

Initially, I had this table as a clustered index (to safe space) but because the table has quite the amount of inserts (1000 / hour) it was very slow because of all the disk access as it had to constantly swap the 10GB of data around. Would it help if the fill factor was set lower (like 70) to get around this? Of course, it would also mean more wasted space but if this could save a lot on the index it might be worth it?

This table is used a lot and for performance the index is needed. Running it without an index takes a few minutes to execute, whereas with the index its done within 2 seconds.

Execution plan xml: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tfUxgYrK

Comment: Are you only interested in optimizing this query? Please detail the DML that you're running. Upload an XML actual execution plan of the current best setup that you have.

Comment: And why do you not go away from the 10gb limit by splitting this in multiple databases? Triggers can handle the referential integrity. Or just get a better database - the web edition is not exactly THAT costly and you really will keep running into limits with the express edition.

Comment: I can split it up but as this table is already accounting for the majority of the 10GB limit (7GB) this is merely a delay of a few months and doesn't really help. I can split the data into multiple databases but it would make everything overly complicated. I don't think one can purchase the web edition, I haven't seen it anywhere for sale. I'll see if I can get the execution plan. I'm not really specifically looking into optimizing this query (its fast enough as is) but rather in reducing the size of this table (the indexes account for 5GB on 2GB of data).

Comment: Added EP XML to first post.

Comment: Looks like your primary key may be better as a clustered index with the column order of Table_1_Id, Table_3_Id, Table_2_Id. This would likely give you a huge performance gain. As usr stated get rid of the other indexes.

Comment: Are you doing anything to maintain your indexes? rebuild / reorganize?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the primary key for uniqueness. Your NCI already provides that uniqueness. You can get rid of one of those indexes. That should save some space.

You can save the space that the other index uses by making it clustered. You notices performance problems due to, apparently, randomly located inserts. This is plausible. Consider changing the column order of the index so that inserts will happen in only one or a few places. That way all pages affected will tend to be cached. The working set required by DML will be low.

The DML perf problems are probably not due to page splits. These cause mostly CPU load and fragmentation. The perf problems are probably because random pages must be read from disk.

1000 inserts per hour are not a lot. Consider accumulating writes into a delta table that is small and fully cached. Move the rows over to the main table in a background process. That way DML latency is off the critical path. Selects would either need to tolerate staleness or `UNION ALL` the delta table.

Comment: The NCI doesn't have a uniqueness constraint at the moment, this seems like a great idea to save space on the PK. Regarding the order, would it matter much? Per user that is adding new entries, its like 100 similar values for Table_3_Id, 50 similar for Table_2_Id and 100 distinct values for Table_2_Id. There are 700000 different values for Table_3_Id, 500000 for Table_2_Id and also 500000 for Table_1_Id. Would the fill factor help here? The performance problem was with inserts (very high CPU and disk usage was shown for sqlservr.exe), select worked fine. I had a fill factor of 95 back then.

Comment: The fill factor helps with page splits but 1000 rows/hour cannot cause high CPU due to page splits in any way. Must be something else. If you want post the DML execution plan. Is any of the columns you insert with mostly sequential like an ID or timestamp? That column would be a great leading index column to concentrate the activity to a small working set. It might break using the index for selects though.

Comment: The execution plan is in the startpost (http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tfUxgYrK). Table_3_Id is the only column that has some degree of ordering (100 times a 1, 100 times a 2, 100 times a 3, etc). Inserts happen later on with the same value probably once a month, but only a few at a time (5-6).

Comment: The number of distinct values is not that important. More important is that they are positioned at similar spots. For example an index on a datetime column with the current time would always write to the end of the table.; I meant the plan for the slow DML. Only if that is a concern for you.